# iOS Use Name of Array as label in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, plist

I currently have a `plist` that stores a bunch of labels for rows in a `UITableView`, and a second `plist` that stores settings.

What I'd like is when you create a new row, the name of that row is stored as the name of an `array`, and the associated settings are stored inside the array.

Is is possible to have a label from the name of an array? How would I do this? How would I make it store what's entered into the text field as an array?

Thanks,

Chris

I've got my textfield saving as an array in a plist using this bit of code

```
- (IBAction)saveViewerItems
{
    // get paths from root directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    // set the variables to the values in the text fields
    self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];


    // create dictionary with values in UITextFields
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: data, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: (@"%@", text), nil]];

    NSString *error = nil;
    // create NSData from dictionary
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

    // check is plistData exists
    if(plistData)
    {
        // write plistData to our Data.plist file
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Which works and I can see it is saved. Now I just need to use the name of the array as the name in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I've just stumbled across another issue - each time I add a new item it adds it at the same position in the plist - overwriting the old one..

Comment: `have a label from the name of an array` do you need outlet names?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean - basically under Root in the plist, I need the user entered textfield to be stored as the name of an array, and the row in the table to get the label for the row as the name of the array. Does that clear it up?

Comment: @ChrisByatt In this case: `[plistDictionary setObject:someArray forKey:textField.text];`

Comment: And if I wanted to use the Key as the label for a row I can do that too?

Comment: As you said when write something into your file it will overwrite entire things. One thing you can do is read the content of file into a dictionary.. Update in that dictionary write back to the file. Do you want to write multiple items??

Comment: I've fixed the issue of overwriting, but I can't get the array keys to display as labels in the table view - ill update my code later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your problem fully. As  mentioned in the above comments do something like this
Store you array like

```
[plistDictionary setObject:someArray forKey:textField.text];
```

in `cellForRow`

```
 NSArray *keys = [plistDictionary allKeys];
 cell.textLabel.Text = [keys objectAtIndex : indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Currently my textfield is being stored into a `plist` using this bit of code